# Get full list of errors associated with stream_socket_client() in PHP

Tags: centos, php, tcp

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.stream-socket-client.php

The PHP function stream-socket-client() gives back errors as:

**errno:**
Will be set to the system level error number if connection fails.

**errstr:**
Will be set to the system level error message if the connection fails.

When testing the function I have so far managed to record these errors:

```
errstr:"Connection timed out" errno:(110)
errstr:"Connection refused" errno:(111)
errstr:"php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not known" errno:(0)
errstr:"No route to host" errno:(113)
```

But I am assuming there a quite a few others I need to know about, so how can I find out the full list of possible errors?

This is on a Centos 8 server.

Answer (score -2):

> I am assuming there a quite a few others I need to know about ...

You would only need to know what the errors codes were if your code were planning to do something "useful" with them if and when it received one, for example attempting to re-connect a "broken" connection and, thereby, hiding this situation from the User.

If all you intend to do is log the error message somewhere, then you don't really need to know *all* the different combinations, just how to receive *any one* of them and what to do with it when you do.

Comment: I do actually need to perform different actions based on the various results, it's more than for the purposes of logging. For example a timeout will be handled in a different way to a refused connection.

Comment: @Appalling: Fair enough.  Which ones have you encountered so far in testing?  
Sticking to the "You Ain't Gonna Need It" (YAGNI) idea, why create [potentially lots of] [potentially complex] error-handling code for dozens of error codes that, in practice, you never see?  
Anyway, I /think/ this is relevant page in the Documentation: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.socket-last-error.php

Comment: I wont handle every possible error but at least want to check through a list to avoid missing important ones, that page has a list in the comments that seems to tally with my result so far. I'm wondering where this list came from, I'm assuming it is a linux list.